# INSTR() and GROUP_CONCAT() returning varying results between servers

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I'm having an issue running the same query on a development and production server. My application stores conference speakers and sessions. The development server, running MySQL 5.1, properly returns only the correlating speakers for an event session, but the production server, running MySQL 5.0.9, returns multiple speakers not necessarily associated with that session. (Note: I cannot bring production server up to 5.1 at this time.)

Speakers table:

```
+------------+--------------+
| speaker_id |     name     |
+------------+--------------+
|        100 | John Doe     |
|        200 | Steve Rogers |
|        300 | Tony Stark   |
+------------+--------------+
```

Sessions table:

```
 +------------+------------------+
| session_id | session_speakers |
+------------+------------------+
|          1 | [100]            |
|          2 | [100,200]        |
|          3 | [300]            |
+------------+------------------+

SELECT 
s.session_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sp.name SEPARATOR ' & '), 
FROM 
sessions s
LEFT JOIN 
speakers sp ON INSTR(s.session_speakers, sp.speaker_id)
GROUP BY 
s.session_id
```

Development server results for session_id = 1

```
'John Doe'
```

Typical production server results for session_id = 1

```
'John Doe & Steve Rogers & &'
```

Comment: Is this your exact query?, it seems to be missing a part of the join condition here: `ON INSTR(s.session_speakers, sp.speaker_id)`

Comment: This is an abbreviated version of the query to protect table names, but yes, that's what I have. What am I missing in the `JOIN` clause?

Comment: Well, a join condition?, you know, `condition1 = condition2`?

Comment: The join condition is the `INSTR` function. A `JOIN` doesn't need an equal sign, it needs an expression that can be evaluated to a boolean.

Comment: Ah, ok. I did try doing `INSTR(s.session_speakers, sp.speaker_id) > 0`, but that didn't seem to change the result.

Comment: @VincentSavard you are right. It still makes more sense to actually add the comparison, but it's true

Comment: @blackairplane: Are you sure the problem lies in the query? From what I see, your tables seem not to contain the same data. I doubt running this query on 5.0 or 5.1 has any significant difference.

Comment: I suspect the data is different on the two machines.  The use of `instr()` in this context is rather dangerous.

Comment: Yes, the data was the first thought, but I created the production tables from a dump from the development servers, so the data is identical.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the query that the data is not the same. If I were you, I'd take another look.

Comment: @blackairplane What happens when you have a `speaker_id = 1000`?, you'll get that speaker and also `speaker_id = 100`

Comment: Is there a better option than using `INSTR()`? There isn't a way to get duplicates in the way you are asking @Lamak since all `speaker_id`s are actually 4 digit codes such as 1000, 1200, 2400.

Comment: @blackairplane What would be better is if you had a normalized table with `session_id, speaker_id` instead of one table that concatenates them

Comment: @Lamak You are correct. I will probably have to approach it that way. I was hoping to modify the existing query and not the structure from another's architecture. That makes sense though. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normalize your table layout:

```
speakers
+------------+--------------+
| speaker_id |     name     |
+------------+--------------+
|        100 | John Doe     |
|        200 | Steve Rogers |
|        300 | Tony Stark   |
+------------+--------------+
```

and

```
sessions_to_speakers
 +------------+------------------+
| session_id | session_speakers |
+------------+------------------+
|          1 | 100            |
|          2 | 100            |
|          2 | 200            |
|          3 | 300            |
+------------+------------------+
```

and

```
sessions
+------------+--------------+
| session_id |     name     |
+------------+--------------+
|          1 | Session 1    |
|          2 | Session 2    |
|          3 | Session 3    |
+------------+--------------+
```

Then you could use a simple "join" to get all the Speakers:

```
SELECT * FROM speakers INNER JOIN sessions_to_speakers ON 
sessions_to_speakers.session_speakers = speakers.speaker_id
WHERE sessions_to_speakers.session_id = 1;
```

Suggestion:
Fix your column names. don't repeat table names if its not a foreign key. i.e. the `id` of the `speaker` table should be called `id` (**not** `speaker_id`). ONLY when referenced from the `session_to_speaker` table, it should be called `speaker_id` (same for session and the reference)